# NSCursor issue with drag gesture

Tags: swift, swiftui, mouse-cursor

I need to use deferent cursor for a view, but it seems onHover modifier and gesture modifier got conflict with together. As you can test the code the cursor is not stable in drag process and it change shape for some reason! Is there any better approach for this?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var offset: CGSize = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Color.yellow
                .frame(width: 500, height: 500)

            Circle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .offset(offset)
                .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local)
                            .onChanged { dragValue in
                    NSCursor.pointingHand.push()
                    offset = CGSize(width: dragValue.translation.width, height: dragValue.translation.height)
                }
                            .onEnded { _ in offset = .zero; NSCursor.pointingHand.push() })
                .onHover(perform: { isHovering in
                    
                    if isHovering {
                        NSCursor.pointingHand.push()
                    }
                    else {
                        NSCursor.arrow.push()
                    }
                })
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Remove cursor changes from gesture handlers.

Comment: @Asperi: If I do that the cursor change the shape in first drag, so it is a must to push NSCursor there, you can try it for yourself.